# About the Dirichlet conditions and the Fourier series of the sine function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

One of the Dirichlet conditions, at least in the texts I've used, is: "$f$ must have a finite number of maxima and minima."

This is not true for the sine function as its derivative is the cosine which equals $0$ at an infinite number of points. However, isn't it rather strange that the sine function can't be expressed as a Fourier series when odd functions are described by a sum of sines?

Moreover, by orthogonality, taking $2π$ as the period, all of the cosine coefficients are $0$ and all of the $n \neq 1$ sine coefficients are also $0$, clearly demonstrating that there is a Fourier series for the sine function: namely, itself.

Is it simply that the Dirichlet conditions only apply to functions outside the basis of the Fourier vector space?

Comment: the condition is actually "f must have a finite number of maxima and minima." in the period interval as any (continuous) periodic function has infinitely many maxima and minima on the line pretty much by definition

Comment: The more general Dirichlet condition is that the function being expanded in a Fourier series is of bounded variation on the interval in question. Really, the finite number of max and mins was leading up to the more general theorem where one assumes the function being expanded is of bounded variation.